# I have Direct tv plugged into a gfci protected receptacle. All of the receptacles on same circuit will go dead, but not trip the gfci. Why?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, gfci

Ok the GFCI is located in the 5th wheel upstairs bedroom/sink. It is protecting 4 of the receptacles in lower level next to sink and tv/stero area.
I have a direct tv (tailgater) plugged into the protected receptacle.  This receptacle along with the other 3 keep dropping power. I have a lamp plugged into one of the 3 receptacles just to monitor this.
The light will blink, it will also go out and stay out for longer periods of time, 30 mins or so and then come back on. Usually GFCI does NOT trip.
I have taken each receptacle apart and checked for loose connections but unable to find the cause. Anybody got an idea what I am missing?
Have checked all GFCI receptacles and they all seem to be working according to the GFCI tester.

Comment: Forgot to add that I have replaced the circuit breaker, by passed the GFCI by just connecting black to black and white to white, all with same results, power keeps going off and on just on that circuit.

Comment: That really does sound more like a loose connection than anything else. Or perhaps a GFCI which has become unreliable and should be replaced.

Comment: I concur with @keshlam assessment (+1); symptoms point toward bad/loose connection or bad GFI/receptacle upstream. Check the wiring schematic (it should have come with the trailer in the "manuals packet") for junction boxes upstream in the wire circuit.

Answer (score 1):

If you have bypassed the GFCI receptacle and still have problems, then there must be a loose connection between the GFCI and the breaker. Here are the places to look:

- At the GFCI, are the wires connected by a screw, or by push-in? The push-in connections are unreliable - I have had a receptacle "fry" because of poor connections, and it was installed by an electrician. Installers like them because they are fast, but I always go with the screw connection.
- At the breaker, is the breaker making good contact with the power bus? If the bus is corroded, even a new breaker might not make good contact. Try plugging the breaker into a different slot, if there is one to spare.
- Also in the panel, is the neutral (white) wire screwed down tightly?
- Are there any other outlets between the panel and the GFCI receptacle? If so, make sure the twist-on connectors are tight, and that the splice is not made through the receptacle.

Note that loose connections will not trip a GFCI. Neither will short-circuits between hot and neutral - they will trip the breaker in the panel. Also, nothing "upstream" will trip a GFCI. And once a GFCI is tripped, it won't reset itself.

Comment: not only the breaker connection to the buss but make sure that connection to the wire is tight also.